# Meteor reactive function for Template updates

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to solve the following problem in Meteor.js:

I have a HTML element that appears in a template only if the user is logged in:
`{{#if currentUser}} <input ...> {{/if}}`. After the HTML element appears I need to execute a JS command on it. Thus I need some kind of callback that happens *after* the Template is updated. How to achieve this?

None of the reactive data sources I know of do the trick in this case as for example the `Meteor.user()` source triggers dependencies *before* the Template is updated. Also see my prior question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720716/meteor-onrendered-only-called-once/29720891).

Comment: why not just use a hook for the login event? http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin would that not work, or is that still before the template update?

Comment: Yes indeed that fires before also - I have tried it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor your template code to put the content of the `{{#if}}` block helper inside a child template, that will get it's own `onRendered` life cycle event triggered only when both the condition is met, and the new HTML content implied is inserted in the DOM.

HTML

```
<template name="parentTemplate>
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{> childTemplate}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="childTemplate">
  {{! whatever}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.childTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  // here you go
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add needed code into `autorun`.

```
Template.mytemplate.onRendered(function() {
   Tracker.autorun(function() {
     user = Meteor.user()
     if (user) {
        // Your code here
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: nope! This, as I have explained in my post, does not work! As explained the `Meteor.user()` reactive source triggers  autorun BEFORE the template is updated and thus the JS code which I need to run on the inserted DOM element fails.

Comment: Could you show how your onRendered with autorun and your template looks like?

Comment: `onRendered` contains my JS code I want to run on the `input`. So does my `autorun` callback together with `if( Meteor.user() )`. The `autorun` callback is defined on global scope but I have tested it by adding an `alert` and it is indeed run - but the jQuery I use inside the callback does not find the `input` field which appears only afterwards.

Comment: Is Meteor.user() inside or outside autorun?

Comment: `if( Meteor.user() )` is inside autorun. And sorry but again "no" to using `onCreated` for jQuery template manipulation - quote Meteor docs "Callbacks added with this method called __before__ your template's logic is evaluated for the first time".